# Why can't I `.call` Array.prototype.splice on a string?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I understand I could and probably should use `substring` :)

For educational reasons, I want to know why I can't use `call` to do a splice operation on a string, which I understand to be an array-like object. It seems like this should work:

```
Array.prototype.splice.call('filename.jpg', -3, 3).join(''); // return the last three chars
```

Throws error `TypeError: Object.isSealed called on non-object` in V8.

Comment: Maybe because strings are immutable. *"which I understand to be an array-like object."* it's true that primitive values are converter to their object counterpart, but they are still immutable.

Comment: Though I'm not sure where the error comes from. Firefox throws `TypeError: property Array.prototype.splice.call(...) is non-configurable and can't be deleted` which is even more obscure (since it doesn't look like we are deleting `Array.prototype.splice.call`).

Comment: Array.prototype.splice.call(new String('filename.jpg'), -3, 3).join('');

Comment: @dandavis: What about it? FWIW, `.splice` already converts the `this` value to an object, so that's equivalent to passing a primitive string.

Comment: @FelixKling:  except a primitive string errors, so something is not equivalent...

Comment: @dandavis: Ah, it doesn't error in Chrome, but it does in Firefox (same error).

Comment: @FelixKling: i hate it when you're right almost as much as i hate it when FF and Chrome differ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Javascript, strings are immutable; they can't be changed after they're created. So there's no "set char" or "splice" methods because a string can't be changed. You can, however, call `split('')` on them to turn them into arrays, so you can use `'filename.jpg'.split('').splice(-3, 3).join('')` for the same effect.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, makes sense. Also explains why I can use `slice` directly, because it doesn't modify the original object.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert it to an array object first

```
Array.prototype.splice.call('filename.jpg'.split(''), -3, 3).join('');
```

Comment: If you convert it, there's no longer any reason to use `Array.prototype.splice.call`.